# Python: how to get text from html file

Tags: python, html

I have a folder with some `html-file` with

```
import os
indir = 'html/'
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(indir):
    for f in filenames:
        page = open(f)
```

But it returns me `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '0out.html'.`

But there are files `0out.html, 1out.html, 2out.html`.
I also try `codecs` but it return this error too.
Where is an error there?

Comment: `page = open(os.path.join(root,f))`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre but how can I get content of this html file? (I need html code)

Comment: `page = open(os.path.join(root,f)); contents = page.read()`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepend the path to the file.

```
import os
indir = 'html/'
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(indir):
    for f in filenames:
        page = open(os.path.join(indir ,f)) # <-- note the added path
```

Without it, you are trying to open a file named `0out.html` which is a peer to your `indir`. When you prepend the path, you indicate that it is a child.

Comment: `indir + f` is bad even if it works here. Use `os.path.join` instead

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: but the question shows no research effort: a simple print would have been enough to see that the file did not exist in the current directory And you should use `root` instead of `indir`.